# Design Web Templates

Tags: html, css, templates, web, photoshop

I am a PHP, VB.NET programmer and i like to build websites. I am good at coding but have never done website designing.

Please suggest me some good study resource on Photoshop and flash website design. I have recently made few templates on photoshop but don't know how to code them for valid HTML-CSS.

Please let me know which is the best method to design website template e.g. Photoshop, DreamWeaver etc.

Also provide links to good study and practice resource for the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[Psdtuts](http://psd.tutsplus.com/)

[Smashing magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/)

[Six revisions](http://sixrevisions.com/)

[Nettuts](http://nettuts.com)

These are some that spring to mind. They cover webdesign and development through showcases and tutorials. They also have alot of coverage on frameworks, either mvc style or pure design frameworks like blueprint css and grid 960.

You'll have to search the tutorials on Psdtuts and Nettuts, but there are more than a couple of tutorials for cutting up psds there.

Hope that gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I have to suggest that hasn't been suggested in the prior post is:
http://www.webstandards.org/

This link will help you understand best practices in web design.

Although I like Adobe CS3, I don't like to use the design view - I like the code view.  It's too easy to become sloppy using a GUI editor, IMO.

The most difficult thing I have encountered about web design is scope creep.  Clients want to pay for a mobile home, but move into a mansion.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [this tutorial](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-code-up-a-web-design-from-psd-to-html) from Line25.
HTH

Answer (score 0):

To design a best template for the website, you should go with the Dreamweaver. It is the best software for designing a professional template for your website. For that, you need to learn basic HTML and then you can easily merge it with PHP or .Net. Create an excellent design for the website.